# How to store values in dictionary in decrement order by values in java?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

i am have problem. Actually i am working on some code and that code is written in python but i want to do same problem in java .i got everything but on collection some problem is coming.

i am storing values in dictionary in java :

```
 Dictionary<String, Integer> dc=new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
  String s[]={"red", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue"};
    for(String t: s){

        if(dc.get(t)==null)

           dc.put(t, 1);
    else
            dc.put(t, dc.get(t)+1);
}
```

**output:**

```
{blue=3, green=1, red=2}
```

i want like:

```
{blue=3, red=2, green=1}
```

but this is not the output i want i want like python gave:

```
cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

can any one give me some idea ?

Comment: I don't think Dictionaries maintain order.

Comment: SortedList, or SortedDictionary maybe. However A list or an array would do this, simply fill it in the order you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use a `HashTable`, this is one of the obsoleted collections**.

I'm not sure on the order you want to maintain but there are numerous different `Map` types. A `HashTable` is equivalent to a `HashMap` but is is `syncronized` is a slightly non-useful manner.

Lets go through the options:

**`final Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>()`**

This will create a `HashMap` which, like a `HashTable`, provides **no guarantees** about the order of iteration.

**`final Map<String, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<>()`**

A `LinkedHashMap` is similar to a `HashMap` except for the fact that it maintains a doubly linked list of the elements so that the iteration order of the elements is the insertion order.

**`final Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>()`**

A `TreeMap` is a very different beast to both hash based maps. The `TreeMap` stores its elements in a `Tree` providing `O(1)` lookups and `O(lg n)` puts - it is therefore slower. However, the `TreeMap` keeps all of its elements sorted **at all times**. The default constructor sorts elements by their natural order, so elements must `implements Comparable` and the `TreeMap` will use that to sort the elements.

Given that you are trying to use a `Dictionary` and a `HashTable`, both of which were obsoleted by the release of Java 1.2 in 1998 I would suggest that you read about the [Java Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), specifically about [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) but reading the whole lot won't hurt.

Comment: i knew about `collections api` but how to do this order.